# Puppet cannot find parent resource type

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to set up Puppet to use templates in order to create configuration files for our servers. The current way I am doing this is by using inheritance to pass default values to a class. This allows me to properly separate the data from the rest of the code. An example of this structure is as follows:

```
class grading_properties(
          $home='tomcat-deploy',
          $financialScoreHigh = $grading_properties_defaults::financialScoreHigh,
          $financialScoreLow = $grading_properties_defaults::financialScoreLow,
          $qualityScoreHigh = $grading_properties_defaults::qualityScoreHigh,
          $qualityScoreLow = $grading_properties_defaults::qualityScoreLow,
          )inherits grading_properties_defaults {

  file{"${base}/${home}/company-conf/grading.properties" :
  ensure  => present,
  mode    => '0755',
  owner   => 'root',
  group   => 'root',
  content => template("company/company-conf_pr/grading.properties.erb")  
  } 
}
```

This class is responsible for generating the "grading.properties" config file based on the "grading.properties.erb" template. The "grading_properties_defaults" class which it inherits looks like this:

```
class grading_properties_defaults{
  $financialScoreHigh = 4
  $financialScoreLow = 7
  $qualityScoreHigh = 6000
  $qualityScoreLow = 4000
}
```

The problem I am having is when I try to create the class using

```
class{ "grading_properties" :
  financialScoreHigh => 10,
}
```

from a class in the same module, I get the following error from puppet apply:

`Error: Could not find parent resource type 'grading_properties_defaults' of type hostclass in production at /home/git/puppet/modules/company/manifests/grading_properties.pp:1 on node sv1.company.qa0`

What is the proper way to reference a class in the same module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I simply need to fully qualify my class names in order for puppet to find them. E.g. `class grading_properties_defaults` should be `modulename::grading_properties_defaults`

Comment: The important part of which being that the master must be able to find the class in the module. And yes, this is the cleanest way of ensuring this.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't in the same puppetfile we must write modulename::classname as example:

```
class modulename::role {  

### CODE HERE ####  

}

class role::www inherits modulename::role {

 ### CODE HERE ####

}
```

In the same puppetfile you don't need declare modulename

```
class role {  

### CODE HERE ####  

}

class role::www inherits role {

### CODE HERE ####

}
```

Great material about profile and roles https://www.craigdunn.org/2012/05/239/